# Variable within a variable to replace a string

Tags: bash, sed

So what Im trying to do is take a file(s) which have the following parameter in it which I need to change globally:

```
level value="something"
```

which I need to change all of them to:

```
level value="somethingelse"
```

Im having trouble with my loop and sed script - lets say I have values of the such in the file:

```
level value="ABC"
level value="DEF" 
level value="GHI" 
level value="I DONT KNOW"
```

I need all of them to become:

```
level value="XYZ"
```

The thing is I dont know what all of the level values are, they could be anything. Hence why I am trying to standardize them to one level value. Is there a way of doing this with a loop and sed? I appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: Don't you know how to write a regular expression that matches anything? It's one of the most basic things.

Comment: If you don't, read the regular expression tutorial at regular-expression.info.

Comment: BTW, if your real input is XML, there are better tools you can use for the job. Might be as simple as `xmlstarlet ed -u //level/@value' -v XYZ <in.xml >out.xml`

Comment: Thanks @SLePort that works more or less perfect. Barmar for some reason I was getting hung up with the quotes, I couldnt regex them properly. Charles Duffy yep its a XML I will try with your solution as well. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(level value="\)[^"]*/\1XYZ/' file
```

`level value="` is captured when followed by non `"` characters. Using backreference, captured string is output followed by the new value `XYZ`.